# What is the time complexity of MergeSort without its penultimate merge?

Tags: time-complexity, mergesort

As in, with the two final sublists which are sorted arrays, let's say just for this example (yes it is no longer fully MergeSort but I am interested in the time complexity only), that we finish with a constant time operation involving the two sublists. MergeSort in worst case is $O(n\log(n))$, and not having the final merge would definitely lead to greater efficiency than this, but by how much? Again, I understand that MergeSort has not completed it's full run, I am only interested with its time complexity for my specified run only.

Answer (score 1):

It will still take $O(n \log n)$.

There are four steps in mergesort.

1. Divide the list in half.
2. Mergesort the left half.
3. Mergesort the right half.
4. Merge the two together.

If I understand right, you're asking about removing the fourth step, *in the final stage only* (that is, not in any of the recursive calls).

In this case, you'll still have to do step 1 in $O(1)$, step 2 in $O(\frac{n}{2} \log \frac{n}{2})$, and step 3 in $O(\frac{n}{2} \log \frac{n}{2})$ (since steps 2 and 3 still call conventional mergesort, which is $O(n \log n)$).

So your total time complexity will be $O(1 + \frac{n}{2} \log \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{2} \log \frac{n}{2}) = O(n \log \frac{n}{2}) = O(n \log n)$.

The final merging only takes $O(n)$ time; it's the recursive part that's the real cost.

Comment: @Azxdreuwa In practice you'd get a bit, but asymptotically nothing. It's far outweighed for large $n$ by the cost of the recursive algorithm.